Replacing text on DOM leads to React error: "Text content does not match server-rendered HTML."
I'm writing a Chrome extension to rewrite post titles and snippets on a forum website (e.g. Reddit). It's very straightforward so far:
const postTitle = document.querySelector("<MATCHING_EXP>");

postTitles.forEach(postTitle => {
  const postTitleText = postTitle.textContent;
  postTitle.textContent = "I AM GROOT";
});

When running the extension, sometimes it works and replaces all the post titles; other times, it doesn't and throws https://react.dev/errors/425, which states
Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
It's a given that the text doesn't match, because I'm overwriting it. But I've also seen Chrome extensions that do similar text replacement successfully.
Is there a way to get around this error?

The MutationObserver strategy here seems to work.

Why are you using React if you're directly manipulating the DOM? Either render content using React components or don't use React.

I'm not using React. Their site (that I'm manipulating) is using React.
